# Google Script: appendRow always on top of the sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, append

As I know: 
"*appendRow(rowContents) add values to the bottom of the spreadsheet But how to add data from the form in multiple rows in top of the spreadsheet?*"

Now 
**I am looking for some help to always place the name in the top row of my sheet with `'.appendRow'`**.

---

Here is some parts the code:

```
var range = sheet.getRange("A:D");
range.clear(); 
sheet.appendRow (["A", "B", "C", "D"])
```

The code, data is constantly pulled in row A-D but I want to do some calculation in rows E-H. 
The problem is that with that code "A", "B", "C", "D" is not placed in the top row of my sheet when I write something f.ex. in Cell E.

Grateful for any advice!

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to use `appendRow` at the top of the Spreadsheet. If so, there is a workaround for it. First you will need to insert a row at the top of the document, and after that you will be able to put values there. An example code would be:

```
sheet.insertRowBefore(1);
sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 4).setValues(["A", "B", "C", "D"]);
```

Doing it will *push* all the existing rows to the bottom while you append a new row at the top. You can learn more about `insertRowBefore` in [its documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowbeforebeforeposition). I hope that this fulfills your question, but don't hesitate to tell me if I mistook your issue, so I can help you better.

Comment: thank you very much @Jacques-Guzel Heron! Even though it still breaks in two parts right at the lines with text in Rows E-H. Therefore I can still not do the calculations.

Comment: Hello @Aper, I don't understand your comment. Do you mean that you don't want to move the data in columns E to H while appending a row on top of columns A to D? I understand that columns are named with letters and rows with numbers; isn't that your case?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
sheet.appendRow (["A", "B", "C", "D"])
```

to

```
sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 4).setValues([["A", "B", "C", "D"]])
```

and see if that helps?

Comment: Great thanks a lot it works partly!. But there is one small problem left. Now "A", "B", "C", "D" is written in the first line but the content following in "A", "B", "C", "D" is but in line 2. Do you have any ideas how I can solve it?

Comment: Write the values to row 2 instead ? sheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, 4).setValues([["A", "B", "C", "D"]])